# Classes and relationship design in mvc 3.0

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, database-design

I have currently have the following classes:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public Ticket()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>();
    }

}

public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

My Problem/Question is the following, let's say I create a new Item: "Item1" and set its price to "3.00", I add that Item to a few "Tickets", i.e., "Ticket1": "Item1", "3.00"; "Ticket2": "Item1", "3.00", etc. If after adding these items to the tickets I change "Item1"'s price to "4.00" it would change the price of the ticket I already created, how can I have it change the price for only ticket created after the price change?

This is my ticket controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(TicketViewModel ticketViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var ticket = new Ticket();
            ticket = ticketViewModel.Ticket;
            AddOrUpdateItems(ticket, ticketViewModel.Item);
            context.Tickets.Add(ticket);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(ticketViewModel);
    }

   private void AddOrUpdateItems(Ticket ticket, ICollection<AssignedItem> assignedItems)
    {
        foreach (var assignedItem in assignedItems)
        {
            if (assignedItem.Assigned)
            {
                var item = context.Items.Find(assignedItem.ItemId);
                ticket.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your code? where add the items...

Comment: I think you need to add a `BuyPrice` field to `Ticket`. The property is owned by `Ticket`, not `Item`.

Comment: @Toro, yes I think I'm starting to realize this, as well as adding other properties that I would need.